# Characterisation of Sobolev spaces using eigenvalues of laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I'm trying to find a reference on a result I thought it was obvious, but since I can't find anything I'm starting to doubt...

I'm looking for a characterisation of the Sobolev space $H^s(\Omega)$ (let say $s\geq 0$ for the moment) where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb R^n$ with at least Lipschitz boundary (if needed $\mathcal C^\infty$ is ok).

For me, one has the following
$$\psi \in H^s(\Omega) \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 0} (1+\lambda_n^2)^s \vert \langle \psi,\psi_n \rangle \vert^2 <  +\infty $$
where $(\lambda_n,\psi_n)$ are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the laplacian on $\Omega$ (with suitable boundary conditions like Dirichlet or Neumann).

Is it true ? I can't find any clear reference... Thanks !

Comment: If $s>n/2$, in the Dirichlet case, the functions of the form $\sum_n c_n\Psi_n(x)$, $\sum_n c_n^2\lambda_n^{2s}<\infty$ are continuous and vanish on the boundary. Thus you miss the functions that do not vanish on the boundary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer... $(\psi_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega)$, no ?

Comment: A remark related to what @LiviuNicolaescu is saying is that if you consider $H^1_0$ to define your basis or eigenfunctions, you will obtain this way a characterization of $H^1_0$, not $H^1$, if you choose $s=1$.

Comment: Look at the case $\Omega=[0,\pi]$. The eigenfunctions of the Laplacian with Dirichlet conditions are $\psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sin nx$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. The linear span of this functions is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, but it is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$. To see this look at the $\sin$-Fourier  series associated to the constant function $1$.

Comment: Another way of saying it is that the condition you wrote down obviously describes the domain $D((-\Delta)^s)\subseteq L^2$. This will involve extra conditions ("boundary conditions"), in addition to the functions being sufficiently smooth.

Comment: Ok thanks you all for your answers. But do you know if there are any result on spectral characterization of Sobolev spaces ? Maybe only in the case without boundary (like Fourier series on the torus) ?